# How to lock Firefox tab to domain or URL pattern

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions, browser-tabs

I know Firefox extensions that allow protecting (cannot be closed) and locking (cannot change URL) tabs.  What I need is an extension that locks a tab to a certain domain or URL pattern.

For example, I want to lock a tab to the domain `example.com`. As long as I follow links that are within this domain the tab should show normal (unlocked) behavior, but if I follow a **link to another domain the link should be opened in new tab** -- leaving the locked tab open with a URL within the locked domain.

Even better would be the functionality to lock a tab to a URL pattern. If a URL matches the pattern it is opened in the current tab, otherwise it is opened in a new tab.

Do you know something (preferably an extension for FF 8.0) that provides this kind of functionality.

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly what pinning a tab achieves: right-click tab, select "Pin Tab". More info here: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/pinned-tabs-keep-favorite-websites-open

Comment: +1, but it only works with a mouse flow; it doesn't work when you edit the URL. It can be misleading if you don't know it.